# solidity call(abi.encodeWithSignature) not working

Tags: solidity, callcode, abi.encodewithsignature

I have problems using the "address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(....))" method.
Below is the code I am testing in Remix:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


 library lib {
      event check(bool, bytes);

      function remoteCall(address c) internal
      {
           (bool success, bytes memory data) = c.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("callback(bool)", true));
            emit check(success, data);
      }
  }

  contract main{
     using lib for *;
     event test(bool);

     function useCallBack() external{
         lib.remoteCall(address(this));
     }

     function callback(bool b) internal {
         emit test(b);
     }

 }
```

I always get : success = false , and the "test" event is never triggered.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility of function callback should be changed to public or external.
Since it is internal, the address type c can not have access to this function through the low-level call.

```
library lib {
  event check(bool, bytes);

  function remoteCall(address c) internal
  {
       (bool success, bytes memory data) = c.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("callback(bool)", true));
        emit check(success, data);
  }}

contract main{
 using lib for *;
 event test(bool);

 function useCallBack() external{
     lib.remoteCall(address(this));
 }

 function callback(bool b) public{
     emit test(b);
 }}
```

Comment: thank you very much that was indeed the source of the error....